# How to prevent recursive hierarchies?

Tags: sqlite

It would be helpful if the following two tables had a specific constraint:

```
-- Table: privilege_group
CREATE TABLE privilege_group (
    privilege_group_id integer NOT NULL CONSTRAINT privilege_group_pk PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name text NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT privilege_group_name UNIQUE (name)
);

-- Table: privilege_relationship
CREATE TABLE privilege_relationship (
    privilege_relationship_id integer NOT NULL CONSTRAINT privilege_relationship_pk PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    parent_id integer NOT NULL,
    child_id integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT privilege_relationship_parent_child UNIQUE (parent_id, child_id),
    CONSTRAINT privilege_relationship_parent_id FOREIGN KEY (parent_id)
    REFERENCES privilege_group (privilege_group_id),
    CONSTRAINT privilege_relationship_child_id FOREIGN KEY (child_id)
    REFERENCES privilege_group (privilege_group_id),
    CONSTRAINT privilege_relationship_check CHECK (parent_id != child_id)
);
```

Each parent can have multiple children, and each child can have multiple parents. Processing relationships can be done outside of the database, but is there a way within the database to prevent recursive relationships?

My research shows that it is possible to use [CREATE TRIGGER](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) and to use a **RAISE** function to prevent something from completing, but the possibility of internal depth-first or breadth-first searches in **SQLite3** is unknown to me.

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html, but it's not allowed in a trigger.

Comment: @CL. Would it be possible to write a query that can verify if there is or is not a recursive relationship within the data given no particular start or end point?

Comment: Following the relationships would require a recursive CTE.