# How to check if a parent/child relationship exists in a tree?

Tags: sqlite, recursive-query

Checking if the following tables have a certain relationship among their records would be useful:

```
-- Table: privilege_group
CREATE TABLE privilege_group (
    privilege_group_id integer NOT NULL CONSTRAINT privilege_group_pk PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name text NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT privilege_group_name UNIQUE (name)
);

-- Table: privilege_relationship
CREATE TABLE privilege_relationship (
    privilege_relationship_id integer NOT NULL CONSTRAINT privilege_relationship_pk PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    parent_id integer NOT NULL,
    child_id integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT privilege_relationship_parent_child UNIQUE (parent_id, child_id),
    CONSTRAINT privilege_relationship_parent_id FOREIGN KEY (parent_id)
    REFERENCES privilege_group (privilege_group_id),
    CONSTRAINT privilege_relationship_child_id FOREIGN KEY (child_id)
    REFERENCES privilege_group (privilege_group_id),
    CONSTRAINT privilege_relationship_check CHECK (parent_id != child_id)
);
```

Parents can have many children, children can have many parents. Writing code to process records outside of the database is always possible, but is it possible to use a depth-first (or breadth-first) search to check if a child has a particular parent?

[My related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47947581/216356) received a comment from [CL.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11654) that mentions the [WITH clause](https://sqlite.org/lang_with.html), but my experience with hierarchical queries is rather limited and insufficient to understand, select, and apply the examples on the page to my goal:

- Only worked with hierarchical queries in Oracle.
- Only used to implement "range" number generators (like in Python).
- Only seen how to process records in a broad-to-narrow pattern.
- Not sure if an expanding result set in a hierarchical query is possible.
- Unsure of how to select a depth-first or breadth-first search strategy.

Could someone show me how to find out if a child has a parent if the names of both are known?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard tree search (using UNION instead of UNION ALL to prevent infinite loops):

```
WITH RECURSIVE ParentsOfG1(id) AS (
  SELECT privilege_group_id
  FROM privilege_group
  WHERE name = 'G1'

  UNION

  SELECT parent_id
  FROM privilege_relationship
  JOIN ParentsOfG1 ON id = child_id
)
SELECT id
FROM ParentsOfG1
WHERE id = (SELECT privilege_group_id
            FROM privilege_group
            WHERE name = 'P2');
```

Depth/breadth-first does not matter for this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I hope to test your solution by the end of the week.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to [CL.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47951185/216356) could be this query which has been reformatted and adjusted to use bound parameters that could be plugged into a project that needs to check certain relationships:

```
WITH RECURSIVE parent_of_child(id)
            AS (
        SELECT privilege_group_id
          FROM privilege_group
         WHERE name = :child
         UNION
        SELECT parent_id
          FROM privilege_relationship
          JOIN parent_of_child
            ON id = child_id)
        SELECT id
          FROM parent_of_child
         WHERE id = (
        SELECT privilege_group_id
          FROM privilege_group
         WHERE name = :parent)
```